# How to enter a value into a react-select component in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-select

In my component's `componentDidMount()`, I would like to look for a `window.location.hash` value and if one is found enter it into my React Select component, and then have the component behave exactly as it would if I were to have typed this value into it. That is to say, the menu opens, the options are filtered by this value, the clear button appears, the cursor is located at the end of the value, and clicking anywhere in the box opens or closes the menu.

What I have now, doesn't do that. The value goes into the box, the clear button appears and the menu opens but the cursor goes to the beginning, it does not filter the menu, and clicking in the box only opens the menu if it did not have focus.
https://codesandbox.io/s/pjok544nrx#grape

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "react-select";

import "./styles.css";

const options = [
  {
    label: "apple",
    value: "APPLE"
  },
  {
    label: "orange",
    value: "ORANGE"
  },
  {
    label: "banana",
    value: "BANANA"
  },
  {
    label: "strawberry",
    value: "STRAWBERRY"
  }
];

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      menuIsOpen: true
    };
    this.searchRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let hash = window.location.hash;
    hash = "grape"; // just to get this working in codesandbox's iframe
    if (hash) {
      this.searchRef.current.select.setValue({
        value: hash.toUpperCase(),
        label: hash
      });
    this.searchRef.current.select.focus();
    }
  }

  onInputChange = (options, { action }) => {
    if (action === "menu-close") {
      this.setState({ menuIsOpen: false });
    }
  };

  onFocus = e => {
    this.setState({ menuIsOpen: true });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Select
          isClearable={true}
          isSearchable={true}
          options={options}
          onFocus={this.onFocus}
          onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
          menuIsOpen={this.state.menuIsOpen}
          ref={this.searchRef}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I've played around with a few combinations of settings but haven't gotten it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: In this case storing value in the state would be a better option. You could omit refs stuff. Also with Hooks API you could rewrite it into a functional component which will work like a charm :)

Comment: Actually since it seems what he really wants is to set a default value, and the Select is uncontrolled (tracks its own value internally), there's no need for state or hooks here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying the select's value in `componentDidMount`, set its **default value** during `render`. (Manual modifications of elements should generally be avoided in React.)

`react-select` provides two possible props for setting the default value: [`defaultValue` and `defaultInputValue`](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#controllable-props). `defaultInputValue` seems most appropriate in your case, since it's a "tentative" value as if the user had typed a search query.

Here's the updated part of the code:

```
  render() {
    let hash = window.location.hash || "grape";
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Select
          defaultInputValue={hash}
          // and all the other props from before
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let hash = window.location.hash || "grape";
    if (hash) {
      this.searchRef.current.select.focus();
    }
  }
```

Note that the focusing logic still belongs in `componentDidMount`, and it's okay to use a ref in this case.

Comment: That's much closer. The trouble is that it keeps the focus after a selection. So, subsequently clicking it does not open the menu which now only happens if it does not already have focus. If I add a blur() to an onChange(), that solves that but then it means the user has to move the focus to it if they want to type into it. Ideally I would like for the focus to stay on the select and for the menu to open/close whenever the select is clicked regardless of where the focus is.https://codesandbox.io/s/pjok544nrx#grape

Comment: It's not a huge deal. The user just needs to press Shift-Tab to move the focus, but it would be nice to have if it's possible.